# ArcPy Copy management creating blank records

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I am copying table from source to target.
But some of the records of the rows are getting blank in the copied table.
My environment ArcGIS Pro 2.x.
My script is :

```
def CopyTables(self, sourceWorkspace,targetworkspace):
       arcpy.env.workspace=sourceWorkspace
       sourceTableList=arcpy.ListTables()
       self.Total = len(sourceTableList)
       self.Count=0
       arcpy.SetProgressor("Setp", "{0}/{1}".format(self.Count, self.Total), 0, self.Total, 1)
       for sourceTable in sourceTableList:
          self.Count+=1          
          arcpy.SetProgressorLabel("Creating table {0} {1}/{2}".format(sourceTable,self.Count, self.Total))   
          arcpy.Copy_management(os.path.join(sourceWorkspace,sourceTable),os.path.join(targetworkspace,sourceTable))
          arcpy.AddMessage("Created table {0} at {1}".format(sourceTable,targetworkspace))
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is this good enough?

Comment: According to PEP8, you can use any indent scheme you want, so long as you want to use 4 spaces. Six then three is going to distract any developer who looks at your code.

Comment: This shouldn't be happening with `arcpy.Copy_management` tool. This tool copies the source item, thus no selections or anything like that. It basically does a 1:1 copy. I couldn't guess why it would be dropping attributes (blank rows). You could get the messages and print them from the copy tool to see if there are any warnings about something gone wrong.  `r = arcpy.Copy_management(...)` >> `print(r.getMessages())`